# Alternative to RemObjects RemotingSDK

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, mqtt, grpc, remobjects

I'm looking for an open source alternative for commercial use to the **RemObjects Remoting SDK**.

I'm currently using Remoting SDK in the following scenario:

- A number of windows service applications (5 to 10) act as servers and retrieve/provide data. These applications are developed using **.Net Framework 4.6 (Windows service C#)**.
- Several client applications (50 to 100) connect to each of the servers to consume the data provided by the servers. These clients are developed using **.Net Framework 4.6 (WPF C#)**.
- Remoting SDK RODL file defines the methods used by clients and servers to exchange data. Some of the methods are common calls that each client fires to retrieve data from the servers, some others are events that the servers fire and the clients receive automatically.

I would like to find an alternative open source library/framework to implement the communication between clients/servers in this scenario with the possibility to have both the clients calling the servers and the servers informing the clients when a certain event happens.

I have really basic knowledge regarding **RPC** and **MESSAGE QUEUES** and I've heard about **gRPC**, **MQTT** and **RabbitMQ** (which I've started to study in depth).

I would like to receive some suggestions/observations/links/guides by developers who are using one or more of these technologies in the .Net environment to solve scenarios like the one I've described to suggest me which solution will better fit the case.

Comment: I think it is a good idea to separate the data handling from the event signalling. For Data, a REST API may also be a good fit. For event signalling you may take SignalR into account. I deliberately do not suggest a "best practice". That would be OT and I don't know enough about your system. Just some hints for you to have a look into.

Comment: Thank you @Fildor for your suggestion. I will take into account studying SignalR.